# Clang complete vim how to show documentation?

Tags: c++, clang, clang-complete

I just installed clang complete plugin for vi. It autocompletes well, and is also showing all function with their parameters. But it doesn't show their documentation (c++). I want to see the functions + their documentation in the scratch preview window. How can I enable it ?? Or the required documentation is missing from my pc, do i need to install it ?

Thank You

Comment: C++ doesn't have a standardised documentation. You'll have to use sites like http://en.cppreference.com/ I think the best you could see would be the function signatures.

Comment: ok, i have cpp reference documentation, so where should i put it, such that clang complete can know ??

Comment: Displaying documentation is not a supported feature of clang_complete.